# Can I have docker-compose restart a container when a file changes?

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

Docker-compose is nice- using `docker-composer up -d` will restart all containers where the `docker-compose.yml` has changed. It will not however pickup if I have changed the `traefik.toml` that one of my container needs to read on startup.

Is it possible to have `docker-composer` take arbitrary files into consideration when recreating containers?

Comment: No. Extend the container’s entrypoint and create such logic for yourself.

Comment: Too bad, but please feel free to use as answer instead comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can, if you set up a volume for your files in question (example below) or locate the volume on your system as docker creates it.

```
volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: .
      target: /srv/www
```

Simply set up a `watch` command or cronjob to check the files. If a change is found you can simply `cd {build dir} && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d`

I recommend you have a script to launch both the watcher and docker-compose or an alias for ease of use.

An alternative, you can have the docker container check its own files, and if it sees a change just `exit`. Have a cronjob or watch script running which runs `docker-compose up -d` in response to the container not running.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, Docker-compose is just a handy tool to ease starting containers, it doesn’t care about your state.

To mimic such behavior you can extend the entrypoint of the image and handle such use case by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use inotifywait to track **docker-compose.yml** changes and then call **docker-compose up -d** so that only services with changed configuration will restart.

If you want restart traefik container then inotifywatch the traefik.toml file and docker-compose restart [traefik-service-name-here]. You can also rebuild and recreate services as well.

Here is part of my development bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PID=0
trap 'kill $PID' EXIT

if [ -z "$(which inotifywait)" ] ; then
  echo "Install inotify-tools"
  exit 1
fi

while true; do
  sleep 2;
  inotifywait -qm --event modify --format '%e' ./docker-compose.yml | echo ""
  docker-compose up -d &
done &
PID=$!

docker-compose  up

kill $PID
```