# Docker Compose Load New Files to Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, nodes

I have a Docker Compose file that starts an Angular, React and Python application.
I would like the container to reload once a file is being modified on my computer locally.

For example, If I change the file "package.json" on my computer, I wish that the new file will be reloaded on the relevant container and the npm process to restart and continue working with the new files.

Is this possible?

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    server:
        build: ./insurance_site
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        restart: on-failure            
    angular:
        build: ./fuse
        command: gulp serve watch      
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        restart: on-failure
    react:
        build: ./react
        command: npm start         
        ports:
            - 3001:3001           
        restart: on-failure
    admin:
        build: ./admin-tools
        command: npm start     
        ports:
            - 3002:3002
        restart: on-failure
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do this by mounting the directory from your host machine in your container. Then run it with whatever hot-reload tool suitable.

Comment: Yeah, you don't do this with docker, you do it with the software inside the container (which will be different for each technology)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I change the file "package.json" on my computer, I wish that the
> new file will be reloaded on the relevant container

Use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/). They do exactly that.

> I would like the container to reload once a file is being modified

This one is not as simple as adding two lines to a `docker-compose.yml` file. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55209103/can-i-have-docker-compose-restart-a-container-when-a-file-changes), it might help.

Comment: Can you maybe help to edit the Docker Compose file for me?
I still unable to use the local storage and reflect it on the containers

Comment: @Avihai You need to add, for example, this: 
`volumes:
  - ./:/path/inside/container` 
"./" means that you are sharing the whole folder where your docker-compose.yml is. This means that the folder where your docker-compose.yml is will be reflected in the folder "/path/inside/container" inside the container.